# Problema al insertar en la base de datos Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Este es mi código, aunque ponga las comillas dobles "", me sale el error.

Código:

```
$ db.contactlist.insert({nombre:'Daniela', correo:'danielaarcehernandez1@gmail.com', numero:'(506) 6188-4715'})
```

Me da este error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{nombre:'Daniela','

Comment: Hola, el insert lo estás ejecutando en el shell de mongodb? Si es así no veo ningún error en el. Si no, entra al shell y deberías de poder hacer el insert.

Answer (score -1):

si intenta usando  `db.contactlist.insertOne({nombre:'Daniela', correo:'danielaarcehernandez1@gmail.com', numero:'(506) 6188-4715'})` puede servir.

Answer (score -3):

(Editado)Este error puede aparecer cuando no estás posicionada en ninguna base. Antes de ese insert quizas hayas olvidado hacer `use db TuBaseDeDatos` para que db. apunte a la base donde se encuentra contactlist. Esto es necesario para que db sea una referencia válida.Suerte.